# Optimize U-SQL by forcing creation of vertexes when querying azure sql db tales

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm querying tables in an Azure SQL DB from Azure data lake analytics, and are experiencing ineffecient queries. 
The queries are simple, all `SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL Datasource EXECUTE @"SELECT *FROM externalTable`. This table consist of more than 60million rows. 
The challenge is that during the execute of the u-sql script retrieving all of these 60 million rows, u-sql only splits these operations down into one vertex, making it impossible to scale the job.
If I split the query into X other "part queries", where I retrieve a piece of the total rows in each part query, and then combining all part queries at the end, I obviously get X vertexes. 
To demonstrate "part queries":

```
       SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL Datasource EXECUTE @"SELECT *FROM externalTable 
  where registered >= GETDATE()-10000 and Registered !> GETDATE()-8000
    union all
     SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL Datasource EXECUTE @"SELECT *FROM externalTable where registered >= GETDATE()-7999 and Registered !> GETDATE()-6000
```

My question is, is this the preferred way of querying external data sources efficiently, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing SQL Azure database server and Data Lake resources participating on cross database queries in the same region for better performance.

You can also retrieve all those millions of records in batches by parameterizing your elastic queries on the Azure SQL Database side. Parameterized operations can be pushed to remote databases and be evaluated remotely on the Azure Data Lake side. Read more about it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/).

Comment: The Azure SQL DB and ADL store is located in the same region. 

I believe I'm already utilizing paramaterized operations that are pushed to the remote Azure SQL DB, as the example query in the original post executes way faster with the condition, then without it.

Do you think there is a better way then my example query in the original post to properly distribute the work in an ADLA job for my situation?

Comment: I cannot suggest you more ways to try and test performance. Parameterizing queries and having resources on the same region are my only suggestions. Maybe an expert on the Data Lake side can help us here and provide us a better way to do it. Let's wait for more answers.